# React Native - MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, google-signin

I'm trying to implement google sign in in my app which I'm making with react native. However, I have to basically change the entire MainActivity.java file.

I'll be changing this

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    View.OnClickListener {
```

This changes a lot of things as it's not extending ReactActivity anymore, it's now extending AppCompatActivity.

My question is: Is it alright to change what MainActivity extends? Isn't ReactActivity necessary? Also, ReactActivity seems to have methods that AppCompatActivity doesn't such as `protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {`.

By the way, where I'm getting AppCompatActivity is 
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java
which is Google's github repo for Google Sign In.

Another question I had is currently, I have to change MainActivity.java in order to get Google Sign In working. When I try to implement something else, say video capturing do I create a new MainActivity.java file such as VideoActivity.java, or do I do all the changes for everything in the one MainActivity.java file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, ReactActivity extends (android.support.v4.app.)FragmentActivity and you can pass it to enableAutoManage. There should be no problem using it as your base class.

The Sign-In api itself doesn't require any UI code, but to save you some boilerplate code, it's suggested to use it together with GoogleApiClient.Builder.autoManage which requires a FragmentActivity. Even for apps having non FragmentActivity, they can still use Sign-In api without enableAutoManage (Then they should manually call connect() / disconnect() of their GoogleApiClient like instructed here:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client)